# SQL Parameterized Order By sort

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    #temp_SuspenseResults
ORDER BY 
    (CASE When @SortBy = 'DueDate' and @SortDir = 0 THEN DueDate END) ASC,
    (CASE When @SortBy = 'DueDate' and @SortDir = 1 THEN DueDate END) DESC,

    (CASE When @SortBy = 'DBAction' and @SortDir = 0 THEN DBAction END) ASC,
    (CASE When @SortBy = 'DBAction' and @SortDir = 1 THEN DBAction END) DESC,  

    (CASE When @SortBy = 'State' and @SortDir = 0 THEN State END) ASC,
    (CASE When @SortBy = 'State' and @SortDir = 1 THEN State END) DESC,

    (CASE When @SortBy = 'FirstName' and @SortDir = 0 THEN FirstName END) ASC,
    (CASE When @SortBy = 'FirstName' and @SortDir = 1 THEN FirstName END) DESC,

    (CASE When @SortBy = 'LastName' and @SortDir = 0 THEN LastName END) ASC,
    (CASE When @SortBy = 'LastName' and @SortDir = 1 THEN LastName END) DESC


OFFSET 
    @PageStart ROWS
FETCH NEXT 
    @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

I got a new requirement that I need to sort on multiple parameter. I know that we can order by multiple parameters such as

```
Select * from #temp_SuspenseResults order by DueDate, DbAction
```

But if I have

```
Declare @SortBy Varchar(100) = 'DueDate,DbAction'
```

How do I sort by multiple values as `@SortBy` is a singular parameter value. Any sugguestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Short answer - dynamic sql. You already have one question with examples. Adapt that to handle the sorting. Presumably you left out the same change to your direction parameter?

Comment: Performance of this query will likely be quite atrocious since no indexes can effectively be used in the sorting (of course the paging offered by `OFFSET`/`FETCH NEXT` is itself a performance problem if you're paging through very many rows, but that's another matter). I recommend reading [this](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for more background information on how to write effective dynamic queries (it specifically deals with parameters for `WHERE`, but most of the same would apply for `ORDER BY` clauses). Ultimately you might not even need a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by doing the following:

```
Declare @SortBy VARCHAR(50) = 'DueDate,DbAction'
Select value into #SortParams from string_split(@SortBy, ',')
SELECT --top 100
        *
FROM
    #temp_SuspenseResults
ORDER BY 
    (CASE When 'DueDate' in (Select value from #SortParams) and @SortDir = 0 THEN DueDate END) ASC,
    (CASE When 'DueDate' in (Select value from #SortParams) and @SortDir = 1 THEN DueDate END) DESC,
    (CASE When 'DBAction' in (Select value from #SortParams) and @SortDir = 0 THEN DBAction END) ASC,
    (CASE When 'DBAction' in (Select value from #SortParams) and @SortDir = 1 THEN DBAction END) DESC,
    (CASE When 'State' in (Select value from #SortParams) and @SortDir = 0 THEN State END) ASC,
    (CASE When 'State' in (Select value from #SortParams) and @SortDir = 1 THEN State END) DESC,
    (CASE When 'FirstName' in (Select value from #SortParams) and @SortDir = 0 THEN FirstName END) ASC,
    (CASE When 'FirstName' in (Select value from #SortParams) and @SortDir = 1 THEN FirstName END) DESC,
    (CASE When 'LastName' in (Select value from #SortParams) and @SortDir = 0 THEN LastName END) ASC,
    (CASE When 'LastName' in (Select value from #SortParams) and @SortDir = 1 THEN LastName END) DESC,
```

Comment: Is there really any value to selecting multiple sort columns when the order of columns is ultimately fixed?